# Forward HttpWebRequest from Windows Azure worker role - on premise wcf

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

Using Windows Azure Service, and exposing a WCF service endpoint from on premise (behind firewall, NAT ....)  is it possible to make available an intranet site to a worker role in Azure?

Basically I want to be able to make an HttpWebRequest request from a worker role in azure to a site in on premise for example http:// intranet.domain.net. Is this possible? Or how can I make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. You have a few options (non-trivial)

1) You will need to build a custom "proxy" that receives requests from Service Bus (over say WebHttpRelayBinding) and then forward the request to "local" IIS using HttpWebRequest or other HTTP clients. Note that this is a lot of work and needs thorough testing of corner cases (e.g. authentication scenarios). Also, it doesn't work with custom domain names (e.g. intranet.domain.net) over "https".

2) Alternatively, you can split the content/web-site and business-data/logic into separate pieces. You can host the content directly at a public site. This public site can then talk to a web-service in the intranet over NetTcpRelayBinding (or one of the *HttpRelayBinding) and execute business logic or retrieve the data.